# How to use vlookup to return the last value in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

For example, my table which I will call Table1 (I have defined this as a name) is added to as new data comes in. How can I use vlookup to retrieve the 2nd column value of the final (last) data point at the bottom of Table1?

Answer (score 2):

Is the first column numerical or text?  You can use the range lookup option and search for a value that is going to be greater than any value in your table.  If your first column contains words, try:

```
=VLOOKUP("ZZZZZ", Table1, 2, TRUE)
```

or, if your first column is a five-digit number, try:

```
=VLOOKUP("99999", Table1, 2, TRUE)
```

And it just occurred to me that this will work too, but is slower.  Define the first column of Table1 as Table1Col1.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(Table1Col1), Table1, 2, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically update the column you're selecting you can use a MATCH() formula to fill in the col_index_num value. For example:

```
=VLOOKUP("d", Table1, 2, FALSE)
```

will return the value in the second column. whereas:

```
=VLOOKUP("d",Table1[#All],MATCH("value2",Table1[#Headers],0),FALSE)
```

will return the value in the column whose header is value2. Even more dynamically, you can write it like this:

```
=VLOOKUP("d", Table1, MATCH(Table1[[#Headers],[value2]],Table1[#Headers],0), FALSE)
```

which will update automagically if you rename the table column headers

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Table1,2,MAX(Table1Col2))
```

Explanation:  `=VLOOKUP(**Data being looked up**,**Name of Table or data range**,**column of data being looked up**,MAX(**Name or data range of data being looked up**))`

It will bring back the last value of the rows which match the lookup_value

Answer (score 0):

Answering mainly to give a modern answer for current searchers ("modern" = 2021).

You'd use `XLOOKUP()`. It is not a perfect replacement and will not suit some situations. But this one is a simple one and one its beta release was redesigned for doing.

The feature of interest is it has a parameter to search from the end back toward the beginning so... slamdunk.

Reading the answers though, I noticed there is no definitive answer for the question in terms that would have worked when posted. The middle answer doesn't even address the question at all and the third one is mendacious to the nth degree. It uses something fancy to generate the Boolean value `TRUE` when just typing `TRUE` (or `0` for thems whats prefers that) would do precisely the same thing. Almost gives the impression the answerer hoped something fancy looking, something pretentious, would take on the appearance of value. Yikes. And it is NOT NOT NOT right in that while it CAN give a not incorrect answer, it is just by chance. Decent chance, since the main mode of failure will be when the desired value is the absolutely last item in the range, but given this could be date based especially, that stands a pretty decent chance of happening.

The first answer gives some practical things to try and depending upon your data, one of them, or something inspired by them, might work well for you. Not like the third one which is pretty con-man inspired and would give quite a few a strong sense of confidence in the results leaving them gob-smacked when the boss comes shouting about a failure.

However, they are just practical things and not necessarily solutions. There is a standard approach to this, available "manywhere" on the internet, that uses `LOOKUP()` in a clever way. But how about something much more direct and easier to understand the workings of? (For most, the `LOOKUP()` method, though clever, really clever, and actually really simple, is just baffling, losing them at the first look stage so while they could EASILY grasp it, they never get to that point to realize that.)

The `INDEX()` function can be used to turn a table upside down, so to speak, so the first row presented to the rest of the formula is the last row in the original ("physical") range. It is done by specifying, for the row parameter, something that generates a sequence of numbers starting with the highest row number (highest "index") and falls to 1.

That's done in 2012/2013 using a clever trick to generate the row numbers in a sequence:  `ROW(1:100)` gives a sequence of 1, 2, 3, ... 98, 99, 100. To reverse it you'd think you could just use `ROW(100:1)` but Excel helpfully "fixes" your silly mistake giving you `ROW(1:100)` — whether you like it or not. No way to overcome that. But if you know the highest row number used, and you would so not a problem, you can add 1 to it, so in this example 100 + 1, and then subtract the sequence Excel gives you from that. Since you have 101 - 1, 100 - 2, 100 - 3, ... you get 100, 99, 98, ... on down to 101 - 100, or 1.

Use that for the row parameter of `INDEX()` so reverse the rows to be last to first.

For the columns for `INDEX()`, you have to think past the usual experience with `VLOOKUP()`. Usually, you give it a table/range that may have lots of columns. So maybe A2:W900. You want to search column A and find something in column T (or column 20). So you might have something like `VLOOKUP("cow",A2:W900,20,false)`. Well, `INDEX()` lets you use a bit of a trick to specify only certain columns rather than using all the columns in the range it is given:  the array constant.

`Array Constants` are a way of giving, well, an array... of values to Excel. They look like this:  `{"a","cow",13,999,"fisherman","circu"}. So in this example, you want to have columns A and T, or 1 and 20, so you'd give` INDEX() {1,20}` for the third parameter, the column parameter.

The point of all this is that `INDEX()` builds you a virtual table to use in the formula in place of the real table. The virtual table does not have rows 2-900 and columns A-W. It has rows 900 through 2 and columns A and T only. That function would look like this for the example:

```
INDEX( A2:W900, 900-ROW(1:899), {1,20} )
```

(Remember, you are using rows 2 through 900 so you only have 899 rows, not 900. So Excel row 2 is "index" 1 in the range and Excel row 900 is index 899. 899 + 1 = 900 so you use 900, not 901. Then the numbers in the formula make "sense." Like calling the first hard drive "Drive 0" not "Drive 1.")

Now you have a virtual table of column A and column T ONLY, row 900 first, going down to row 2 last, and this is your table to use in the `VLOOKUP()`. So the full formula to look up the word "cow" and get any exact match... starting at the END and working back toward the beginning, would look like this:

```
=VLOOUP( "cow", INDEX( A2:W900, 900-ROW(1:899), {1,20} ), 2, false )
```

Since the "real" table's data is rows 2-900, this is finding the LAST match by using a table that reversed the data to be rows 900-2. And it only uses the two columns, the one you do the lookup IN and the one you get the data FROM, not all 23 columns of data. Since there are only two columns, the column to return an answer from is always EASY:  it is column 2. "false" ensures an exact match, if any.

And this will ALWAYS work.

As an aside, that array constant we used, `{1,20}`... what do you suppose reversing those values would do? As in `{20,1}`. They reverse the order of the columns. So if you wish to use `VLOOKUP()`, but your lookup column in this example is column T and you want results from column A, you'd be out of luck. (The old "Out of luck accident" from my time in the US Navy's nuclear power program. Man, "OOL" accident... we were SO close to creating "LOL" years early but... just... didn't... Well, reactor plant accidents weren't a laughing matter I suppose, so maybe for the best, eh?) Your lookup column MUST be on the left of your results column to use `VLOOKUP()`... no bueno!

However, since you create a virtual table that reverses the columns, your lookup column is suddenly ON THE LEFT after all! BUENO!

A further aside, the array constant for the columns (or rows, but usually columns) can use only some numbers, use them in any order, AND use them more than once if you like.

Remembering "modern method":  Nowadays we can use `SEQUENCE()` to directly generate that reverse sequence from 899 down to 1.